# How can expand all PivotTable of Google SpreadSheet by Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want expand all rows had Collapse in a SpreadSheet by Script:

I had this code:

```
var pivotTables = sheet.getPivotTables(); 
  
  for (var i = 0; i < pivotTables.length; i++) {
    var pivotTable = pivotTables[i];
    var rows = pivotTable.getRowGroups();
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
      rows[j].expand();
    }
  }
```

But occur error: `TypeError: rows[j].expand is not a function`

How can expand all PivotTable of Google SpreadSheet by Google Script?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, it seems that SpreadsheetApp.PivotGroup has no method of `expand`. [Res](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-group)
- I was looking for the method for expanding and collapsing the groups of rows and columns before. But, unfortunately, I couldn't find it. But, fortunately, I confirmed that when Sheets API is used, expanding and collapsing the groups of rows and columns of the pivot table can be achieved.

From the above situation, in this answer, I would like to propose using Sheets API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

And, please set your sheet name and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  
  // Retrieve pivot table using Sheets API.
  var obj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: [sheetName], fields: "sheets(data(rowData(values(pivotTable))))" }).sheets[0];

  // Create request body by expanding groups of rows.
  var requests = obj.data[0].rowData.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    if (r.values) {
      r.values.forEach((c, j) => {
        if (c.pivotTable) {
          var pivotTable = c.pivotTable;
          ["rows"].forEach(e => { // If you want to expand both rows and columns, please use ["rows", "columns"].forEach(e => {
            if (pivotTable[e]) {
              pivotTable[e].forEach(pr => {
                if (pr.valueMetadata) {
                  pr.valueMetadata.forEach(vm => vm.collapsed = false);
                }
              });
              ar.push({
                updateCells: {
                  range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: i, endRowIndex: i + 1, startColumnIndex: j, endColumnIndex: j + 1 },
                  rows: [{ values: [{ pivotTable }] }],
                  fields: "pivotTable"
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  
  // Request the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, all row groups of all pivot tables are expanded.
- When you want to expand both row groups and column groups, please modify `["rows"].forEach(e => {` to `["rows", "columns"].forEach(e => {`.
- If you want to collapse all row groups, please modify `pr.valueMetadata.forEach(vm => vm.collapsed = false);` to `pr.valueMetadata.forEach(vm => vm.collapsed = true);`.

#### References:

- [Class PivotGroup](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-group)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PivotTable](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/pivot-tables#PivotTable)

Comment: Thank you, i had expand a sheet ok, but Can i send a request for multi sheet?